# During Maven Build Junit Tests runs fine, but why they fails, if I runs JUnit test manually?

Tags: java, maven

I have some problems with my maven project. I have created some JUnit test in my maven folder src/test/java.

If I created my maven project with "mvn clean install" on command line or in Eclipse IDE with the runs configurations like "clean" and "install" all test will be runs fine and don´t occurs some error.

But if I runs the JUnit test manually, one of these Junit test fails. But what is the reason, why maven doesn´t recognized this fact? Here is a code snippet of my maven pom.xml file:

```
    <plugins>       

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <source>${source.jdk}</source>
                <target>${target.jdk}</target>                  
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>                
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>
                        jar-with-dependencies
                    </descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Source-JDK>${source.jdk}</Source-JDK>
                        <Target-JDK>${target.jdk}</Target-JDK>                                      
                        <Project-Build-SourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</Project-Build-SourceEncoding>    
                        <Maven-Build-Timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</Maven-Build-Timestamp>
                    </manifestEntries>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly-jar-Id</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Here is the Junit code which fails:

```
 public void testProperties(){      

    String build_time = Parameters.BUILD_TIME.getParameter();

    Map<String, String> allProperties = MetaInformation.Properties();       
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> currentEntry : allProperties.entrySet()){

        if(currentEntry.getKey().equals(build_time)){               
            String project_build_value = currentEntry.getValue();               
            Assert.assertEquals(true, build_time_value != null && build_time_value.equals(""));             
        }           
    }

}
```

The Property File includes the following values:

```
buildTime=${timestamp}
encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}
```

The Junit test, which is reading out the value "buildTime" is failed. "timestamp" is a value, which based on the pom.xml of my maven project. It gives me the the following properties:

```
<properties>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

${maven.build.timestamp} represent the point of time, which my maven project was build with the command mvn clean install. The JUnit test, which read this value, makes some trouble since the variable "project_build_value" is empty during execute this JUnit test. But why and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I use runs as "Junit" to start my Junit test class. When i get an error,w hich was created from the Assert class: expected <true> but was: <false>

Comment: We're going to need the code for your failing test and probably the code for what it is testing.

Comment: I added some new information

Answer (score 5):

Most-likely, this test of yours depends on the execution of another one which produces some files, other resources or store data somewhere (for example in a database or something). TDD (test-driver development) states that any tests you write should be their own independent entities, meaning: any test you write should be completely self-sufficient and not depend on things produced by other tests executed before it.

Simply put: make sure your test has all the proper resources/data produced in it's `setUp()` method or that the required test resources are copied by Maven before your test executes.

Debugging test cases which depend on resources/data which is produced by other test cases is never a good idea, as, at some point in time, you will forget that another test is meddling with your resource and will wonder why the results are not what you were expecting.